# Where to get android-9 libraries from?

Tags: android, git, github, sdk

I pulled the Xabber sources from github and wanted to try to compile it. project.properties of Xabber show an entry

```
android-9
```

which points to the used system libraries/version.

Amazingly my Android SDK (Linux) does not have a version 9! There is a gap exactly between 8 and 10...so, was this version taken back by Google for some reason or is it a problem of my installation?

Where can I get android-9 from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best option is to edit this to be a higher API level, like 10, so that you are working with a still-active build target.

If you really want to download API Level 9 stuff, check the Obsolete checkbox in your SDK Manager.